# adjust two images and save Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I am trying to load canvas with two or three images from database.

I have the page working so I can move images and resize them like this [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/).

But now I would like to have a (save image) button under the canvas so when you are done moving and adjusting your images on the canvas you can save the canvas as one jpg.

Is it possible to ad a save canvas or save Image button with the code linked to above?
I have looked but can't find anything this simple.

I don't need any fancy image editor apps just exactly what is in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Saving a canvas as an image is one of the features of the Canvas and is quite easy.
You can use a simple event handler or form submit handler in javascript to implement this.
Here's a code sample using jQuery to obtain the canvas and redirects to a png of the canvas
contents.  The key function is toDataURL().  Read more about it here http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl

```
canvas = $("#maincanvas").get(0);

.. your drawing operations here ...

// The save image button event handler 
var toPNG = function() {
  return window.location = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};
$('button#save').click(toPNG);
```